# Mice in R: How to exclude a variable already in the initialization process of Mice

Tags: r, initialization, r-mice

I am new to R and I am using mice in order to impute some missing values.I need to exclude a variable (called TankId) already in the initialization process. 
I know how to exclude a variable once the initialization is done but I do not have any clue on how to exclude it also in the initialization step. 
Here is the code:

```
initialization <-mice(train, maxit=0)
complete_train<- complete(initialization)
meth = initialization$method
predM = initialization$predictorMatrix
predM[,c("StatId","YYYYMMDD","Original")]=""
meth_[c("MinValue")]="norm.predict" 
imputedTrain<- mice(....)
```

So my question is: how do I do `predM[,c("TankId")]=""` in the initialization step?

The reason why I need to do it is that if I put TankId in the initialization it won't run because the data is too big. However I need that variable to be in my dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found an answer by myself in the function quickpred():

```
initialization<-mice(train_data,pred=quickpred(train_data,include= 
c(...),exclude= c('TankId', 'ItemId')), maxit=0)
```

Of course if you have a better one please let me know.